# 'CountVectorizer' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, data-science

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
pipe = Pipeline([('count_vec', CountVectorizer()),    
                 ('lr', LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear'))])
pipe_params = {'remove_stopwords': [None, 'english'],'ngram_vec': [(1,1,)(2,2), (1,3)],'lr__C': [0.01, 1]}
gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=pipe_params, cv=3)
gs_fit=gs.fit(count_vec['label'])
pd.df(gs_fit.cv_results).sort_values('mean_test_score',ascending=False).head
```

`As i run this code

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-e9e666a843e5> in <module>
     11 
     12 gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=pipe_params, cv=3)
---> 13 gs_fit=gs.fit(count_vec['label'])
     14 pd.df(gs_fit.cv_results).sort_values('mean_test_score',ascending=False).head()
     15 

TypeError: 'CountVectorizer' object is not subscriptable`
```

Answer (score 1):

According to sklearn's documentation, `CountVectorizer` produces a sparse matrix.

```
This implementation produces a sparse representation of the counts using scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.`
```

I see what you are doing there but the output of a `CountVectorizer` produces something like this

```
array([1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
  dtype=int64)
```

As you can see, it does not have a `column`s or `row`s. Thus, `count_vec['label']` is not a valid call.

In order to `fit` the model you will need to use the `labels` column from the dataset which you are using. Since the `Gridsearch` is using the `pipe` you do not have to provide it with the post `CountVectorized` data but can provide the `GridSearch` with the original `labels`.

Sklearn CountVectorizer: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html